# How to link two objects saved in different places in Django

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am trying to achieve something similar to what Facebook is doing: in a blog post, when you post a link to an article, it automatically fetches the tag to get the image, title and description, and then render it on the page.

When drafting the post, I use a `websocket` thanks to Django Channels to send the link from the front to the backend to retrieve the different elements via Beautiful Soup. And then I send them back to the front to display them.

The issue arises when I want to save the post along with the shared url elements. To manage the post creation, I use a CBV `PostCreate`. I can save the shared url elements in the consumer. But the two objects are not linked and I don't know how to get the `SharedArticle` object id and save it with the post.

I have two models: `Post` and `SharedArticle`.

Here is my `consumer.py`

```
class UrlConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        chat_room = "shared_url"
        self.chat_room = chat_room
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            chat_room,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })


    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("receive", event)
        page = urlopen(event['text'])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
        title = soup.find('meta', property='og:title')
        img = soup.find('meta', property='og:image')
        description = soup.find('meta', property='og:description')
        article = {
            'title':title['content'],
            'img':img['content'],
            'description': description['content'],
            'url': event['text']
        }
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.chat_room,
                {
                    "type": "chat_message",
                    "text": json.dumps(article)
                }
            )

        await self.create_shared_article(
                        article['title'],
                        article['description'],
                        article['img'],
                        article['url'])
```

Here is my `views.py`

```
class PostCreate(UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'draft', 'publish', 'category']

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        content = form.instance.content
        title = form.instance.title

        send_email(title, content)

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        form.fields['content'].widget = PagedownWidget(show_preview=False)
        form.fields['publish'].widget = SelectDateWidget()
        return form
```

And my `models.py`

```
class ArticleShared(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             null=True,
                             default=1,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL
                             )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,
                                   auto_now_add=False,
                                   default=now())
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 null=True,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    article_shared = models.ForeignKey(ArticleShared,
                                 null=True,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the primary key of the ArticleShared back through the channel after you discover it. To do this, you would need to change the order of your create_shared_article and group_send.

```
async def websocket_receive(self, event):
   # .. look up data
   article_shared = self.create_shared_article(...)
   await self.channel_layer.group_send(
      self.chat_room,
      {
         "type": "chat_message",
         "text": json.dumps(
            { "article" : article, "pk" : article_shared.pk }
         )
      }
   )
```

Then, in your front-end code, you can insert the "pk" into the form field for article_shared before saving the Post.

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! I just had to reinsert the `await` there: `article_shared = await self.create_shared_article(...)` otherwise It get `'coroutine' object has no attribute 'pk'`